# Basis of polynomial

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, polynomials

I tried to do this but no result. Can anyone please explain me and make me understand this)

Let $a \in \Bbb R - \{0\}$, and consider the family of polynomials
$$B_a=\{x^2,\ (x - a)^2,\ x^2(x - a),\ x(x - a)^2\}$$

Prove that $B_a$ is a basis of $P$.

Comment: P is a polynomial of degree 3

Comment: What is "over a"? What is it supposed to be?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/j8mtrcrox/

Comment: I don´t understand the exercise :S

Comment: Do you know what a basis is?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what is P in this problem

Comment: i already wrote it, it a polynomial of degree 3 :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a\in \mathbb{R}_0$. Then $$B_a=\left\{x^2,(x-a)^2=x^2-2ax+a^2,x^2(x-a)=x^3-ax^2,x(x-a)^2=x^3-2ax^2+a^2x\right\}.$$ We check that these four vectors are linearly independent by calculating the determinant of the following matrix:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1&1\\
1&1&-a&-2a\\
0&-2a&0&a^2\\
0&a^2&0&0
\end{pmatrix}.$$ This matrix contains the vectors in the columns after applying the coordinate transformation w.r.t. the standard basis of $P$. Notice that this determinant is $a^4\neq 0$. Hence the four vectors are linearly independent. Since the dimension of $P$ is four, this is sufficient. This method is fairly efficient but you need to be familiar with basic linear algebra. If the determinant of this matrix is non-zero, the matrix is invertible. Hence the system of equations $AX=0$ has only one solution, namely $X=0$. It follows that the only linear combination of the columns equal to zero is the zero combination. Hence the columns are linearly independent.

Comment: But, i don´t understand how to it using a linear combination :_

Comment: By converting the polynomials in $B$ to column vectors, we can verify if those vectors are LI and span $\Bbb{R}^4$ by calculating the determinant of the matrix made up of them. If the determinant is not $0$, then the matrix is invertible and thus its columns are a basis for $\Bbb{R}^4$. This implies the original polynomials are also a basis for $P$ because the coordinate vector transform is an isomorphism - it preserves LI and spanning

Comment: Yes, it is okay. I trust you :).

Comment: But, i trying to do it using a linear combination as Rory Daulton told me above and i got stuck

Answer (score 1):

In your problem, $P$ clearly is the vector space of all polynomials of degree less than or equal to three with the one variable $x$--i.e. the polynomials $px^3+qx^2+rx+s$. It is asking about a "basis" in the linear-algebra sense. If you do not know what a basis is for a vector space, you need to look it up: you should not be doing such problems without knowing that.

The standard basis for $P$ is $B=\{1,\ x,\ x^2,\ x^3\}$. Your set $B_a$ is also a basis of $P$ if and only if you can find a linear combination of the polynomials in $B_a$ that simplifies to $1$, another that simplifies to $x$, another to $x^2$, and another to $x^3$. Find and show those linear combinations and you are done.

You will need the fact that $a\ne 0$, so expect to use some fractions with powers of $a$ in the denominator.

That should be enough hints to get you on your way.

Comment: Nice of you to edit. I was going to do it, but you beat me. :)

Comment: Yes, i know what a basis is :_. I hadn´t realized what the exercise was asking me. Also, i got a serious problem with polynomials :S.